# Cakephp complex query

Tags: cakephp, find

I have the sql code and i want to do in cake php but i dont know how and i don't want to do it like that

```
 $obj->query($sql);
```

This is my query:

```
"SELECT dbfiles.amount, MONTHNAME(cases.enquiry_date) as Month FROM cases
   INNER JOIN services ON cases.id = services.case_id
   INNER JOIN dbfiles ON services.id = dbfiles.service_id
   WHERE cases.status = 2 AND YEAR(cases.enquiry_date) = '2012' AND dbfiles.type = 'INV'
   AND cases.currency = 'EUR' GROUP BY dbfiles.invoice_num ORDER BY Month DESC; "
```

Comment: can you post your models also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $obj is of class `Case`

```
$obj->find('all', array(
   'fields' => array('dbfiles.amount', 'MONTHNAME(cases.enquiry_date) as MONTH',
   'joins' => array(
      array(
         'table' => 'services',
         'type' => 'INNER',
         'conditions' => array('cases.id = services.case_id'),
         'foreignKey' => false
      ),
      array(
         'table' => 'dbfiles',
         'type' => 'INNER',
         'conditions' => array('services.id = dbfiles.service_id'),
         'foreignKey' => false
      )
   ),
   'conditions' => array('cases.status' => 2, ... the rest of your WHERE clauses)
)
```